My manager was bad-mouthing me and the shifts I do in a pub
So while I was away on a trip my manager and boyfriend got into a disagreement over me.
I have a part time contract. I have since I started and when my son was born three years ago we shuffled around my shifts to work with child care as I was a single parent. I work three days a week.
So my manager was shouting loudly in a pub that 'the shifts I do are pathetic' I 'only work 16 hours a week and she bends over backwards for me' - not true, I work 20. And that my head was on the chopping block with the big bosses but she stopped it. Also not true.
This was heard by a whole pub full of people and there are many witnesses.
What can I do in this situation and where do I stand?

Hello Ruth, I'm having a hard time understanding your post, specifically what does you boyfriend has to do there. When you say you "shuffle around your shifts" you mean you sometimes swap the shift on the pub with your boyfriend, so you can look after your child?

There is very little you can do about your manager bad-mouthing you, especially in the service industries, except start looking for work elsewhere or trying to overachieve long enough to change his mind. I submit that a manager who makes public remarks of this sort does not want their mind changed;. they're incompetent at handling staff,  and unless the owner shoots them down for chasing away too many employees they are likely to remain so.

I would also point out that nothing said in a pub, after a few drinks, is especially believed.

When someone acts like an ass in public, just be glad it wasn't you.
This might be not what you want to hear, but shrug it off. There isn't anything meaningful that can be done.
You aren't going to sue him for slander.
It wasn't at work, so it isn't an HR situation. If you are somewhere where it might be made into an HR situation, what would your goal be?
The difference between 20 and 16 hours in a rant in a pub? That leaves me scratching my head as to why you care.
Life is too short for you to get worked up over this. The best advice is mentally move on.
FYI - if it is your real name being shown, consider changing the profile public name.

"It wasn't at work, so it isn't an HR situation" the original was a garbled mess, but the feeling I got was that her shifts were at the pub, that the pub was her workplace... but that may or may not have been the case, I could not point to the actual written confirmation, just my gut feelign reading it.

@nvoigt I can't can't figure out what the boyfriend has to do with it either.

Though I did give this a +1, note that there are cases that even though something did not happen at work it can still be a HR situation.  The most common examples I have seen involve an employee on their own time at home posting something disparaging about their employer on social media.
